# How to move features up and down, inside the layer (after initialization)?

Tags: openlayers, vector, features, draw-order

I want to move features up and down inside a vector layer, with OpenLayers 3.

I have two features: `red` & `blue`.

As you can see im the first image, `blue` is over the `red` feature.

[image: blue over red]

Moving `red` up would mean that it would be pulled to the front, thus showing the whole red feature, and hiding part of `blue`. See the second image.

[image: red over blue]

So, now, red would have been moved up!

I have noticed that the uppermost feature `blue` is at the top because it is created after `red`. So, there is probably some kind of order option inside the feature itself. I have searched but I haven't found it, yet.

I want to change the order AFTER initialization. For example, by doing `vector.moveFeatureUp(red);`

Could you please help me understand how to move features up and down?

**I POSTED A SOLUTION AS AN ANSWER!**

Comment: Isn't it just here that it changes : vector.getSource().addFeatures([blue, red]); > vector.getSource().addFeatures([red, blue]); ? Sorry if i misunderstand your question.

Comment: No. I tried it. But I want to change the order AFTER initialization. For example, by doing `vector.moveFeatureUp(red);`

Comment: For the latest version 7.4, this can be achieved with `feature.setZIndex` method. See this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-z-index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Hicham Zouarhi's tip about the ID, I realized that the ordered the features are drawn depending on the `closure_uid_xxx` property. See an instance of `ol.Feature` in the image below.

[image: closure_uid_xxx]

This uid property changes on reload. So I looked where it came from:

1. I used the ol-debug.js file, that has the google closure library included.
2. I found `goog.UID_PROPERTY_` and saved it as my own local variable `closurePropertyUid`
3. I created a `getFeatures` function that fetches the features by order of `closurePropertyUid`
4. I created a function that swaps the UIDs of two features
5. Now, the `moveFeatureUp` function works without errors

Try it out in this updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/joaorodr84/pen/GqZQqJ) (now with 3 features)

Answer (score 2):

you can retrieve the feature and push it again in the source:

```
function moveFeatureUp(feature){
    var tmp=feature.clone();
    vector.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
    vector.getSource().addFeature(tmp);
}
```

**Edit:** I think the problem was with the id of the features, now I tried it in your codepen and it works, note that clone() copy the feature without its id so it is possible to push it to the end of the Features array in the source

Comment: It does not work. Please, check out the updated CodePen in my question.

Comment: @joaorodr84 I edited my answer, it was an id problem

Comment: Your solution throws errors. But, it gave me ideas and I found a solution. I posted it as an answer. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: @joaorodr84 you're welcome :) , I checked your updated codepen, It takes 2 clicks on the button to move a feature up ( ex: to move red up when green is on the top) it moves the feature just 1 step up, I would like to know what errors is thrown in my answer, please, since it worked fine on the codepen

Comment: 1) When the feature is already at the top, and you click `moveUp`, it throws an error as you can see [here](http://codepen.io/joaorodr84/pen/oLOvON). 2) I chose not to use `clone` because I wanted to keep the reference to the feature. I wanted to avoid creating new features. 3) It takes 2 clicks because the `moveUp` function performs only one move at a time. That is exactly what I wanted. ... Thanks again! :)

Comment: @joaorodr84 I see now, my bad. I thought that you wanted to push the feature up over all the other features with one click

Comment: No problem. Maybe I didn't explain correctly what I wanted. You help was very useful. :)